# Автоматическое копирование обновленных данных в БД каждые 3 минуты

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!

Мой код парсит инфу с другого сайта путем  (`file_get_contents`)  копируя (`insert into`)  в БД mysql.

Это все происходит путем запуска странички,  а можно реализовать, чтоб страничка автоматически брала нужные данные и копировала в БД каждые 3 минуты?

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Можно использовать `cron` (имхо самый нормальный метод).
2. Можно создать HTML-страничку с AJAX-опросником вашего файла, которая будет каждые 3 минуты запрашивать его. Открыть HTML-ку и держать её открытой, ну это костылёк такой, если лень заморачиваться.

Comment: думаю cron     
Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: За что минус?

Answer (score 0):

```
header( "refresh:180;url=script.php" );
```

в конец скрипта, но для таких вещей есть cron

Comment: Ну да, но опять же, нужно держать саму страницу открытой.